# Firebase Rule to Allow Reading Nodes Only Where a Child Node Equals auth.uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am new to writing Firebase rules and am not entirely sure if what I am trying to achieve is even possible, but:

I have a data structure like:

```
grids
  $key
    athlete: "QmXZqXO3V1Zayu9wPJSKb4v816j1"
    exercise: "Push-Ups"
    timestamp: "1493683200000"
  $key
    athlete: "QmXZqXO3V1Zayu9wPJSKb4v816j1"
    exercise: "Push-Ups"
    timestamp: "1493683200000"
  $key
    athlete: "Can't read me!"
    exercise: "Push-Ups"
    timestamp: "1493683200000"
```

When I try and read the list `grids` I want only to be able to read nodes where the child node `athlete` equals `auth.uid`.

So the list `grids` would only be populated by users' own nodes.

I have tried to achieve this with several rules but to no avail. E.g.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "grids": {
      "$key": {
        ".read": "data.child('athlete').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
{
  "rules": {
    "grids": {
      "$key": {
        ".read": "root.child('grids').child($key).child('athlete').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But these don't allow me to read any of the nodes in `grids`. At best I can read an individual node, but not a list.

I think what i have hit here is that 'rules are not filters'.

Can I achieve what I want with rules or do I need to restructure my data?